# select2 unable to search if data source is remote

Tags: jquery-select2

I am using select2 select box to populate and show some server data.  Most of it works fine as I am able to get the results and populate the combo box.  But when I type in the search box, the selection doesn't narrow down the the closest match.

[image]
I found the problem was because the backend URL doesn't support searching based on the string provided, while select2 keeps making multiple search request to backend, based on user entered text.  The legacy backend code returns results in one shot, which is populated into the combobox the first time.

My question is, how do I get the the select box to focus to the closest matching result, without making multiple Ajax calls.  I want the search to happen in the results which are already fetched.

Thanx to anyone helping me out on this.

My ajax call is like below, if this helps...

```
select2: {      
  placeholder: 'Select Next Plan Id',
  allowClear: true,
  id: function (item) {
    return item.id;
  },
ajax: {
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: "jsonp",
  url: "http://172.16.7.248:8480/app/gui?action=1&type=11",
  data: function (term, page) {
    return { search: term };
  },
  results: function (data, page) {
    return { results: data.aaData };
  },
  success : function(data, status, xhr) {
    var html = "<option value=''>None</option>";
    $.each(data.aaData, function(i, item) {
        html += "<option data=" + JSON.stringify(item.id) + " value=" + item.id + "'>" + item.id + "</option>";                 
    });
        $('#nextplanid').html(html);

        self.prop('data-loaded', 'true');
    },
    error : function(data, status, xhr) {
    }
},

formatResult: function (item) {
  return item.id;
},
formatSelection: function (item) {
  return item.id;
},
initSelection: function (element, callback) {
    return $.get('/getText', { query: element.val() }, function (data) {
    callback(data);
  });
}
```

},

Comment: Did you solve this? Please post your solution if so.

Comment: Well.. I have make a work around by implementing query function to do the searching in the pre-fetched data and thus returning a sub-set of results.